# SQL - How to check the status of salary incremented or decremented?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to check if the salary has been increased or decreased. How can I do that?

A new column can be opened and written as ascending and descending.

I am using SQL Server.

Table:

[image]

Comment: Use `LEAD`/`LAG`?

Comment: what is the difference? @larnu

Comment: [LEAD (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)/[LAG (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Heisenberg You can answer that ***by yourself*** by reading the online help.  *(They're exact opposites)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a CTE (or a sub-query) with a `LAG()` to get each row's preceding `wage` value.

Then use a `CASE` expression to categorise the change.

```
WITH
  data_lagged AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    LAG(wage) OVER (PARTITION BY CurrAccCode ORDER BY StartDate)  AS wage_lag
  FROM
   yourTable
)
SELECT
  *,
  CASE WHEN wage > wage_lag THEN 'increase'
       WHEN wage = wage_lag THEN 'no_change'
       WHEN wage < wage_lag THEN 'decrease'
                            ELSE 'new_wage' END  AS wage_change_mode
FROM
  data_lagged
```